# multiple virtual inheritance and variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In my project I played with the following design :

```
enum {
    A = 1, B = 2, C = 4
};
struct Foo { int foo; };
template <int> struct Bar;
template <> struct Bar<A> : public virtual Foo { int a; };
template <> struct Bar<B> : public virtual Foo { int b; };
template <> struct Bar<C> : public virtual Foo { int c; };
```

Now I can do something fun like :

```
template <> struct Bar<A|B> : public A, public B {};
template <> struct Bar<A|C> : public A, public C {};
template <> struct Bar<B|C> : public B, public C {};
template <> struct Bar<A|B|C> : public A, public B, public C {};
```

So that I can write :

```
Bar<A|C> bar;
bar.foo = 2;
bar.a = 1;
bar.c = 2;
```

Now I would like the generation of the combination classes `Bar<X|Y|Z|..>` to be automatically done when the user creates such an instance.
Is this possible using some template magic ?

Something along the lines of :

```
template <int N, class ...Classes> struct Bar<N> : public Classes... {};
template <int N> struct Bar<N> : public Bar<N, generate_classes<N> > {};
```

where `generate_classes` would be able to generate the list of classes `Bar<N>` should inherit from.

Comment: maybe something like template <bool Enable> A;... etc. that is empty if Enable is false. Then you always include all of them with parameter being a bitcheck on the original number that defines what to inherit.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f9ae646f32b0d53

Comment: Since the flags must be compile time constants anyway, why not simply `Bar<A,C>`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Maybe he does not want Bar<A, C> to be different class from Bar<C, A>, it would be hard to enforce equality in that case.

Comment: What the meaning of `template <> struct Bar<A|B> : public A, public B {};`

Answer (score 3):

No need in fancy schmancy SFINAE, parameter packs or any such dark wizardry.

```
enum {
    A = 1, B = 2, C = 4
};

struct Foo { int foo; };

template <unsigned int> struct Bar; // unsigned because bit fiddling

template <> struct Bar<A> : public virtual Foo { int a; };
template <> struct Bar<B> : public virtual Foo { int b; };
template <> struct Bar<C> : public virtual Foo { int c; };

template <unsigned int i> struct Bar :
    public Bar<i & ~(i-1)>, // only least significant set bit 
    public Bar<i &  (i-1)>  // all other set bits
{ };

// checking
int main ()
{
  Bar<A|B|C> abc;

  abc.a = 0;  // ok
  abc.b = 0;  // ok
  abc.c = 0;  // ok

  Bar<A|B> ab;

  ab.a = 0;   // ok
  ab.b = 0;   // ok
  ab.c = 0;   // error

  Bar<A|C> ac;

  ac.a = 0;   // ok
  ac.b = 0;   // error
  ac.c = 0;   // ok

  Bar<9> x;   // error
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution, but this would create a lot of intermediate class wouldn't it ?

Comment: @YoYo It would inherit linearly.  So if you `Bar<A|B|C>` you get `Bar<A|B|C>` inheriting from `Bar<A>` and `Bar<B|C>`, which then inherits from `Bar<B>` and `Bar<C>`; 1 extra.  In general, you get n-2 extra intermediate `Bar`s I think.

Comment: @YoYo It will, but they are probably no cost at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about somehow generating a list of classes to be inherited you can think of it as choosing them. This one should be inherited, this one shouldn't. This can be achieved by static dispatching through template parameter. So we get a template that based on a bool parameter gives either T or an empty class. It is likely to be optimized (it may even be guaranteed in this case, but I'm not sure what exact requirements given by the standard are) by empty base optimization so there is no memory overhead.

```
#include <iostream>

enum {
    A = 1, B = 2, C = 4
};

template <class T, bool Enable>
struct or_empty;

template <class T>
struct or_empty<T, false>
{
    struct empty {};
    using type = empty;
};

template <class T>
struct or_empty<T, true>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T, bool Enable>
using or_empty_t = typename or_empty<T, Enable>::type;

struct Foo { int foo; };

template <int I> struct Bar : 
    public or_empty_t<Bar<A>, I&A>, 
    public or_empty_t<Bar<B>, I&B>, 
    public or_empty_t<Bar<C>, I&C> {};

template <> struct Bar<A> : public virtual Foo { int a; };
template <> struct Bar<B> : public virtual Foo { int b; };
template <> struct Bar<C> : public virtual Foo { int c; };


int main()
{
    Bar<A|C> bar;
    bar.foo = 2;
    bar.a = 1;
    // bar.b = 2; error
    bar.c = 2;

    std::cout << bar.foo << ' ' << bar.a << ' ' << bar.c << '\n';

    std::cout << sizeof(Bar<A>) << ' ' << sizeof(Bar<A|B>) << ' ' << sizeof(Bar<A|B|C>) << '\n';
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f170fbd873739c38

Comment: Thanks ! I thought the solution you posted in your other comment much shorter and IMHO cleaner. Is this solution really better ?

Comment: @YoYo I just made it cleaner and added an explanation. Tried to decouple choosing an empty class from Bar. My comment was a fast written prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Some machinery to do compile-time unpacking of flags:

```
enum flag_e { None = 0, A = 1, B = 1<<1, C = 1<<2 };

template<flag_e...>
struct flags {using type=flags; constexpr flags(){}};
template<flag_e>
struct flag{using type=flag; constexpr flag(){}};

constexpr flags<A,B,C> all_flags{};

template<flag_e...lhs, flag_e...rhs>
constexpr flags<lhs...,rhs...> operator+(flags<lhs...>, flags<rhs...>)
{ return {}; }

template<flag_e lhs, flag_e...rhs>
inline constexpr flags<lhs, rhs...> operator+(flag<lhs>, flags<rhs...>)
{ return {}; }
template<flag_e...lhs, flag_e rhs>
inline constexpr flags<lhs..., rhs> operator+(flags<lhs...>, flag<rhs>)
{ return {}; }

template<flag_e...fs>
inline constexpr flags<fs...> operator+(flag<None>, flags<fs...>)
{ return {}; }
template<flag_e...fs>
inline constexpr flags<fs...> operator+(flags<fs...>, flag<None>)
{ return {}; }

template<flag_e f, flag_e...fs>
inline constexpr auto unpack( flag<f>, flags<fs...> x, flags<> )
-> flags<fs...>
{ return {}; }

template<flag_e f, flag_e...fs, flag_e c0, flag_e...checks>
inline constexpr auto unpack( flag<f> fin, flags<fs...> x, flags<c0, checks...> )
-> decltype( unpack( fin, x+flag<flag_e(f&c0)>{}, flags<checks...>{} ) )
{ return {}; }

template<flag_e f>
inline constexpr auto unpack( flag<f> fin )
-> decltype( unpack( flag<f>{}, flags<>{}, all_flags ) )
{ return {}; }
```

Then we use it:

```
template <int> struct Bar;

template <class flags> struct BarImpl;
template <flag_e...fs> struct BarImpl<flags<fs...>>:
  Bar<fs>...
{};
template <int flags> struct Bar:
  BarImpl<decltype(unpack(flag<flag_e(flags)>{}))>
{};
struct Foo { int foo; };
template <> struct Bar<A> : public virtual Foo { int a; };
template <> struct Bar<B> : public virtual Foo { int b; };
template <> struct Bar<C> : public virtual Foo { int c; };
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e023639b04dd20fe).

The code that lets you have bundles of flags and individual flags can be made more generic at the cost of mentioning the `flag_e` type more often.

I made it overly slick, with the ability to say `flags<A>+flags<B>` and get `flags<A,B>`, because I like that notation.

I then wrote `unpack`, which takes `flag<A|B>` and produces `flags<A,B>`.

In C++14 and 17 things get slicker, which folds and return type deduction and the like.

Comment: Ughhh ;) I think if I had the need for the unpack and flag struct somewhere else in my project I might go for this one, otherwise it looks overkill compared to the other proposed solutions.